# How can I see lint messages in next dev (next.js)

Tags: next.js, eslint, lint

When I use `next dev` (a command from the next.js library) it would be nice to see the warnings I get when I run `next lint` as part of the watch/compile/serve "loop". Is this possible?

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61829116/4316850

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but my solution is to always run `next lint` before `next dev`. I added a new command in my `package.json` like so:

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev-lint": "next lint && next dev"
  },
```

Now, if `next lint` passes (no errors, only warnings), it runs `next dev`; otherwise, the process stops there until the errors are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add these settings to the package.json and run `npm run dev:ts`. This will ensure files are checked & linted while having a running app.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "next dev",
    "dev:ts": "yarn dev & yarn ts:watch",
    "ts": "tsc --noEmit --incremental",
    "ts:watch": "yarn ts --watch",
  },
```